# Is Kazuki Nakashima a mangaka?

Tags: kazuki-nakashima

I read somewhere that Kazuki Nakashima writes manga, but I don't really believe that.

I mean, as shown in the ending credits for Sword Art Online, the man did the colour setting (read it and weep, but that's what it says).

I also know that he plays big roles in the making of the two animes Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann and Kill la Kill.

With that being said, I saw the guy as more of a anime type person than a writer of manga.

But, my thoughts aside, **does Kazuki Nakashima** ***really*** **write manga**, or is it not true?

And if it is true, please name a few of his works. I know I could just "Google it", but I'd rather you just answer my question, rather than question it.

Comment: "I know Kazuki Nakashima did the color setting for Sword Art Online" - did he? The fellow's a writer, not an artist...

Comment: This question seems absurdly simple. To know other works done by a person, all you have to do is Google it.

Comment: @senshin, that's what the ending credits for SAO say.

Comment: And @Ero Sɘnnin, maybe so, but I'm not the first person to ask a question that Google can provide the answer to. So, maybe you could help instead of delivering a smart comment, m'kay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is a Japanese playwright, novelist and anime screenwriter. [His work on anime mostly as writer.](http://myanimelist.net/people/3328/Kazuki_Nakashima) But according [this interview](http://www.performingarts.jp/E/art_interview/0611/1.html) he did write a manga before.

> You mean the kind of action stories with bright, outgoing, handsome and cool heroes like in the youth mangas rather than stories full of darker emotions like grudges and pathos? **Did you write mangas yourself**?
>
> I did. At university I was in the manga club, and when I got a job at the manga publishing company Futaba-sha (publisher of the Manga Action, also publishes numerous literary books) after university I took my original mangas to the job interview along with my persona vitae with the intention of being hired either as a manga artist or an editor.